# Find missing numbers in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I am practicing for the numerical test and have no idea about solving sequence questions as shown below:-

1) 95, ?, 88, 17, ?, 19, 74

2) 53, 16, 46, 25, ?, ?, 32, 43

3) 3, 8, 16, 29, 50, ?

and such sequences.

I know only arithmetic progression formula -> a(n) = a1 + (n – 1)d

But no idea how to find numbers in-between the series and also un-ordered. If you can provide me some help here by giving explanation how to solve such sequences or any formula, that might help.

Thanks.

Comment: "Find the next term" or "find the missing term" questions are, when no context is given, just glorified versions of "guess which number I'm thinking about" questions, especially when there are finitely many terms. I can justify _any answer_ for _any term_ in _any of those sequences_. So if those are the kinds of questions you will get on your test, then this is a bad test indeed.

Comment: There really aren't any techniques for solving problems like these.  It's not even clear what "solving" them means...many rules will work (polynomial interpolation, for example, always works).  Usually the point is to guess what somebody else had in mind which can be frustrating.  For these, the only one I can see a simple pattern for is the last one (which is just a shift of the Fibonacci sequence).

Answer (score 2):

All such questions are ill-posed, as there are infinitely many right answers.

1. there are two interleaving arithmetic sequences, or at least this seems to be the direction
2. same here
3. This i don't see a natural answer, but starting from 16, you double the number, then subtract one-before-previous, like $2 \times 16 - 3 = 29$ and $2 \times 29 - 8 = 50$. So it could be $2 \times 50 - 16 = 84$,
   or it could be $a_n = a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+5$ or any number could be plugged in.

Comment: For 3, the successive differences are $5, 8, 13, 21$, which seems Fibonacci-like (which would also give $84$ as the next term). I think if you see what your reasoning means for the difference between successive terms, you get the Fibonacci recurrence.

Comment: hmm [so i guessed 84 twice, you say]

Comment: No, more along the lines that I would guess $84$ as well, and I came up with a different reason, but I believe that deep down they are the same reason.

Comment: Now i see that. :-)

Comment: Thanks @dEmigOd and Arthur for your valuable input and explanation.